# xhr send - send file and CSRF token

Tags: html, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to use XMLHttpRequest to send a file object and a string (CSRF Token) to the server but I cant seem to figure out how to add the token:

```
xhr.open("POST", form.action, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X_FILENAME", file.name);
xhr.send(file);
```

Is sending the file, anyone lend a hand on how to attach the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just add

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', '<YOURTOKENHERE>');
```

before xhr.send() ?

As far as I understand your problem, this should solve it. (Might be I misunderstood, though)

Comment: capitalized it, should be 100% now ;)

Comment: If this doesn't work use `xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', '<YOURTOKENHERE>');` -- Notice the difference in case.